# Why does the Part::partw error appear when using DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, symbolic, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.0**

---

I solved the following ordinary differential equation for $F(x)$ using DSolve in Mathematica

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
& A x^2 (x^2 + 1) F'''(x) - \left(3 A (b - 2) x^3 + a x^2 +A (b - 2)x  +a \right)F''(x) \\ 
& + 3 (b - 1) x \left(A (b - 2) x + \frac{2}{3} a \right)F'(x) -(b - 1) b \left(A(b - 2) x + a\right) F(x) = 0 
\end{split}
\end {align}
$$
**Mathematica Input**

```
DSolve[A x^2 (x^2 + 1) F'''[x] - (3 A (b - 2) x^3 + a x^2 + A (b - 2) x + a) F''[x] + 3 (b - 1) x (A (b - 2) x + 2/3 a) F'[x] - (b - 1) b (A (b - 2) x + a) F[x] == 0, F, x];
```

After some time, Mathematica actually produced the closed form solution below. 
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
F(x) = & C_1 ( x + i)^b + C_2 ( x - i) ^b + C_3\left[a  \left(b-1+x \left(1+\sqrt {-(b - 1 )^2}-b \right) \right. \right. \\ & \left. \left. +\sqrt {-(b - 1)^2} \right)+A (b - 2) \left(b-1+x \sqrt {-(b - 1)^2} \right) \right]^b
\end{split}
\end{align}
$$

However, it also gave me an error message

```
Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>
```

From another answer, I found out that

> **Part::partw** - This error occurs when you're trying to obtain a part of an expression at a position longer than the Length of the expression (or subexpression).

**Questions**

- Why does the error message come up in DSolve?
- Is the above solution a valid general solution?
- What algorithm might Mathematica use for this type of ODE?

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Please take a look at this page: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951) and re-paste your code for the differential equation. All those `\[Prime]` are an artifact and should be fixed. It will be a lot easier for people to help you if they can run your code.

Comment: @MarcoB: Thanks for the hint. Typed up the input now, as I currently only have the Wolfram CDF Player available at home. Hopefully it should be working now.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the update. I ran your code and observed the same `Part` error. I am not sure where it comes from, except that it seems to come from inside `DSolve`. I'm afraid that I am not sure about points 2. and 3.

Comment: @TimD You might want to report this to Wolfram Support; perhaps it's a symptom of an internal problem within `DSolve`.

Comment: Can somebody with access to multiple versions please add the customary header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The computation

```
eq = A x^2 (x^2 + 1) F'''[x] - (3 A (b - 2) x^3 + a x^2 + A (b - 2) x + a) F''[x] + 
    3 (b - 1) x (A (b - 2) x + 2/3 a) F'[x] - (b - 1) b (A (b - 2) x + a) F[x];
s = DSolve[eq == 0, F, x][[1, 1]];
```

after further simplification yields

```
s[[2, 2]] = FullSimplify[s[[2, 2]]]; s
(* F -> Function[{x}, (-I + x)^b C[1] + (I + x)^b C[2] + 
   (A (-2 + b) (-1 + b + Sqrt[-(-1 + b)^2] x) + a (-1 + Sqrt[-(-1 + b)^2] + 
   b + x + Sqrt[-(-1 + b)^2] x - b x))^b C[3]] *)
```

which is the solution given in the question.  (The error message in the question is, of course, also produced.)  Indeed, it is a valid solution,

```
Simplify[eq /. s]
(* 0 *)
```

However, it is not the most general solution, as can be seen by forming the Wronskian of the three solutions contained in `F`.

```
Wronskian[List @@ (F /. s)[x], x]
(* 0 *)
```

In other words, the term multiplying `C[3]` is a linear combination of the terms multiplying `C[1]` and `C[2]`.  So there must be a third independent solution.  In principle, it can be obtained using the procedure described [here](http://www.ku.edu.np/kuset/vol8_no2/2_BMT.pdf).  Begin by defining

```
w = Wronskian[eq == 0, F, x] // FullSimplify
(* E^(-(a/(A x))) x^(-2 + b) (1 + x^2)^(-2 + b) *)
y1 = (x - I)^b; y2 = (x + I)^b;
w12 = Wronskian[{y1, y2}, x] // FullSimplify
(* -2 I b (-I + x)^(-1 + b) (I + x)^(-1 + b) *)
```

Then, the third solution is given by,

```
Integrate[Simplify[y2 (y1 w/w12^2 /. x -> xp) - y1 (y2 w/w12^2 /. x -> xp)], xp]
```

Unfortunately, this command returns unevaluated.  Alternatively, the third solution, here designated `y3[x]`, can be obtained by solving

```
DSolve[(w12 y3''[x] - D[w12, x] y3'[x] + 
    (D[y1, x] D[y2, {x, 2}] - D[y2, x] D[y1, {x, 2}]) y3[x]) == w, y3, x]
```

This computation ran for about one half hour, at which point the kernel crashed.  It appears, therefore, that the third solution cannot be obtained in symbolic form.

To address the specific issues posed in the question,

1. Why the error message?  A bug in `DSolve`.
2. Is the solution in the question a valid, general solution.  Valid, but not general.
3. How was the solution obtained?  Unclear (to me) how `y1` was obtained.  However, once obtained, `y1` must be the complex conjugate of `y2`.  The third term is not linearly independent and, in this context, must be considered an error.

By the way, an alternative approach,

```
SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce];
r = DSolve[eq == 0, F, x][[1, 1]]
(* F -> Function[{x}, (-I + x)^b C[1] + (I + x)^b C[2] + 
   (-1 + Sqrt[-(-1 + b)^2] - (1 + Sqrt[-(-1 + b)^2]) x + b (1 + x))^b C[3]] *)
```

produces a different solution, also valid but not general, along with the same error message.

**Version 11.1 update**

Version 11.1 returns three independent solutions, although in terms of `DifferentialRoot` and no error message.

```
SetSystemOptions["HolonomicOptions" -> {"VariableSymbol" -> x, "FunctionSymbol" -> y}];
s = DSolve[eq == 0, F, x][[1, 1]]
(* F -> DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, 
   {-((-1 + b)*b*(a - 2*A*x + A*b*x)*y[x]) + (-1 + b)*x*(2*a - 6*A*x + 3*A*b*x)*y'[x] + 
    (-a + 2*A*x - A*b*x - a*x^2 + 6*A*x^3 - 3*A*b*x^3)*y''[x] + A*x^2*(1 + x^2)*y'''[x] 
    == 0, y[1] == C[1], y'[1] == C[2], y'[1] == C[3]}]] *)
```

(The first line of code provides a cleaner format, as described in the [answer to question 123540](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123541/1063).)  Because verifying the solution with, for instance,

```
FullSimplify[eq /. s]
```

runs seemingly forever, the following can be used to lend credence to the result.

```
rule = Thread[{C[1], C[2], C[3], A, a, b} -> Round[100 RandomReal[{1, 5}, 6]]/100]
sn = First@NDSolve[{eq == 0, F[1] == C[1], F'[1] == C[2], F''[1] == C[3]} /. 
    rule, F, {x, 1, 5}];
f = (F /. s /. rule);
Plot[{(F /. sn)[x], f[x]}, {x, 1, 5}]
(* {C[1] -> 84/25, C[2] -> 417/100, C[3] -> 401/100, 
    A -> 92/25, a -> 237/100, b -> 223/100} *)
```

[image]

Comment: Put another way: *Mathematica* has yet again returned a generic solution.

Comment: Thanks for the well-written answer! I have reported the bug to the Wolfram Support. One more question regarding your answer: Can we conclude the linear dependence for any value of the parameters a, b and A from just knowing that `Wronskian[List @@ (F /. s)[x], x]` is zero? [This article](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379589903935/1-s2.0-0024379589903935-main.pdf?_tid=4789725e-2eca-11e6-bf2f-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1465535880_fd1d2e52b934a54b15ccc185ea741c36) suggests that there are additional conditons.

Comment: @TimD  Note footnote 1 (on page 2) of the reference. `W = = 0` is sufficient for linear independence, if the functions are analytic.  The three functions in the solution (erroneously) supplied by `DSolve` are analytic except, perhaps, at a few isolated points.  Moreover, a bit of algebra is sufficient to show that the third solution is proportional to either the first or second solution, depending on the value of `b`.  So, the three functions are, indeed, dependent.